# Unable to refer image from a php file referenced in another php file

Tags: php

I have

1. menu.php in the root folder
2. loginbar.php in the root folder
3. index.php in root folder
4. images/logo.png in root
5. /blog/index.php in root

Now the image is included in menu.php which is included in loginbar.php. The loginbar.php is used as a complete header which has the logo and menu in index.php which works fine.

But when I copy the code from index.php in root to index.php in blog folder and update the path by prefixing `../` I am not getting the image in blog/index.php because the menu.php is still having the absolute path for the image. How can I get the image from blog/index.php where I include ../loginbar.php which in turn includes menu.php

I hope the query is clear. Its a reference to the already referenced file.

Comment: Use absolute path. `/images/yourImage.jpg`

Comment: @Cid I have updated the question, hopefully I have clarified it. Can you please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to approach this is using an absolute path,
which means, instead of using:

```
<img src="../assets/img/pic.png">
```

You should use instead

```
<img src="http://example.com/assets/img/pic.png">
```

It's so much better if you just define a global variable with the absolute path

```
<?php
   define('ROOT_DIR', 'http://example.com/assets/');
?>
<img src="<?=ROOT_DIR?>img/pic.png">
```

Comment: It's particularly useful when you're using a CDN